# How can I view ETW events within Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, etw

How can I view ETW events from within Visual Studio 2015 for C++ projects?

My C++ project generates ETW events and I would like to capture them and view them from within Visual Studio 2015. Is this possible?

I know there is ETW event tracking for other services (such as Azure ServiceFabric), but I can't seem to find it for the Visual C++ services.

I am aware of the existence of other tools for generating ETW logs and viewing them, I would just like to know if there is a way to do it inside VS.

Comment: I don't know a buildin way. Feel free to create an extension where you can listen to ETW providers and show the results in a Window that you can open during debugging.